# Secondary-menu not floating correct in Drupal 7

Tags: css, drupal-7

I am trying to build a website for a friend, I am building it using Drupal 7.
I have a CSS problem that is driving me crazy. The secondary menu, which I float to the right isn't next to my content. Instead it appears to the right below my content.

I feel like I have tried everything. I have the first menu floating left, secondary floating right, and the content on margin auto left and right.

I also tried clear both on the underlying container but it didn't help either.
I am experiencing this error in both Firefox and Chrome.

The only solution i could find online that i haven't tried yet, is to float right before floating left, because I'd have to tinker with Drupal core.

I actually had the problem before, and rebuild the whole damn website, and it happened again while trying to center my components.

I have changed too much since to press 'undo', so it would be awesome if someone with a lot of CSS knowledge could explain me why this occurs.

If you want to see the problem, its on this page www.mohaaleague.com, in the right bottom, but it should be as high as the left menu....

```
.two-sidebars #content /*the middle element*/
{
    width: 827px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#sidebar-second /*the right sidebar*/
{
    width: 287px;
    float:right;
}

#sidebar-first /*the left sidebar*/
{
    float:left;
    width: 287px;
}

#main  /*the underlying div that holds all the others*/
{
    width: 1650px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: you need to post the html and css for the relevant elements. Typically, though, this happens when you don't define a width for each item or when your margins + widths exceed the parent container. by the way, this is almost certainly not a drupal issue. While drupal does vomit out some of the most unnecessarily convoluted markup of just about any cms, it is still subject to the same css rules as any other system

Comment: @Kai Qinq I added the CSS, I wouldn't know where to find the HTML as it's in Drupal's templates which I haven't touched

Comment: You could right click, inspect element and copy as html for the whole parent of the 2 elements. Might be an eye full for most people so I'll just look at the css and see if anything stands out

Comment: You don't really have those comments in the css do you? // is not a valid css comment. you have to use /*some comment */

Comment: Also, if #content is supposed to be between the 2 sidebars, you have to float it.

Comment: the comments aren't in my code, i tried floating #content, but it didnt change anything. Also I changed the comments to how they should be, so others won't think the same

Comment: This fiddle shows that it works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/z99t75ja/ - but then again, this fiddle is not using your html as far as I know

Comment: @Kai Qing it was Drupal, ill post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw I started from BARTIK theme.

Okay, so I managed to solve it by changing page.tpl.php,a ctually it was something I adressed in my question.

The problem was that float right was being called, before the float left. So I changed the order in which Drupal renders the page. By making Drupal render my second-sidebar first, and then my first-sidebar, and then the content i solved the problem.

I changed page.tpl.php in my themes templates directory like this, if you are reading this and have the same problem change the order of the code to this:

```
       <?php if ($page['sidebar_second']): ?>
  <div id="sidebar-second" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
    <?php print render($page['sidebar_second']); ?>
  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-second -->
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($page['sidebar_first']): ?>
  <div id="sidebar-first" class="column sidebar"><div class="section">
    <?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>
  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#sidebar-first -->
<?php endif; ?>

<div id="content" class="column"><div class="section">
  <?php if ($page['highlighted']): ?><div id="highlighted"><?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?></div><?php endif; ?>
  <a id="main-content"></a>
  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
  <?php if ($title): ?>
    <h1 class="title" id="page-title">
      <?php print $title; ?>
    </h1>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
  <?php if ($tabs): ?>
    <div class="tabs">
      <?php print render($tabs); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
  <?php if ($action_links): ?>
    <ul class="action-links">
      <?php print render($action_links); ?>
    </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
  <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
```